# "To kill a fly with a..."?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

I seem to recall that there is an expression for when you are throwing something too big at a particular challenge: "To kill a fly with a..."? Or am I way off here?

**Edit:** maybe it's not a fly after all? I found [this](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut.html) article talking about 'Using a sledgehammer to crack a nut'.

Comment: someone wrote  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653522/11206)  in a comment: "Using a sledgehammer to miss flies" , but I don't know if this is a frequently used phrase.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

... tactical nuclear weapon?

Google autocomplete suggests "sledgehammer", "bazooka", and "cannon".  I think "sledgehammer" is the only one I've actually heard used, and I suspect it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I like the tactical nuclear weapon suggestion :)I used the Google autocomplete function as well, but none of the options seemed quite right, so I posted the question here. And now I forgot where I was going to use it...

Comment: "Nuke it from orbit" (the only way to be sure) is the new way to say "overkill." I *think* it is from "Aliens," but it is also all over the internet.

Comment: Sledgehammer is how I usually hear it, too.

Comment: @horatio you are correct, it comes from the film "Aliens" where they quite literally plan to leave the planet and nuke the aliens from orbit, "only way to be sure". On a related note, there's a Monty Python sketch where "mosquito hunters" use machine guns, bazookas and artillery strikes to kill a single mosquito.

Comment: I would argue that if a nuclear weapon is used to kill a fly, it's not being used tactically. Unless you're doing it to scare the other flies (so they'll leave you alone), then it would be used tactically.

Answer (score 12):

A Korean proverb exists which states...

> Do not draw your sword to kill a fly.

Comment: Sounds elegant. I wish I would get such quick answers on my questions on StackOverflow! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah this website is suffering from an abundance of knowledgeable enthusiasts and a lack of questions. Quite funny actually.

Comment: Good to know. I do have some to offer from time to time!

Answer (score 8):

Actually the idiom goes, "to *break* a (butter)fly on *the wheel*". The wheel in question being a torture device, for humans rather than flies. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wheel):

> The **breaking wheel**, also known as the **Catherine wheel** or simply the **wheel**, was a torture device used for capital punishment in the Middle Ages and early modern times for public execution by bludgeoning to death.

[image]

The sledgehammer mentioned in the top answer is from a different idiom entirely, "cracking a nut with a sledgehammer". Same idea, of course, but the idioms are not to be mixed and matched at will except for comedic effect.

In German and Russian, there's also "to shoot sparrows with cannons" (*mit Kanonen auf Spatzen schießen/стрелять из пушки по воробьям*). That one hasn't caught on in English, though.

Comment: The "shooting sparrows with cannons" expression is also used in Danish.

Comment: Great answer! Surely deserving of more than +4...

Answer (score 4):

It could be "kill a fly with a sledgehammer", "kill a fly with a cannon", "kill a fly with a bazooka".

To reply to the additional question, "to kill a fly with […]" is the usual phrase. There are other phrases that are used to mean "using something that is excessive".

> Use a surgical knife to slice bread.

Comment: That one must be quite old because nowadays I think most people use "scalpel" instead. "Bistoury" doesn't get a single hit in BNC or COCA.

Comment: _Bistoury_ is specifically a surgical knife, while _scalpel_ is a sharp knife. The CoCa reports just 3 sentences containing "a fly with a sledgehammer"; that doesn't mean the phrase is not frequently used.

Comment: I work in surgical instruments and have never heard of bistoury? My spell-checker caught it. I don't think it's known in Britain or the US.

Comment: Bistoury used to be common in French, but like in English, it seems to have lost out to scalpel.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar phrase ["like burning down a house to kill a fly"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22like%20burning%20down%22%20%22to%20kill%20a%22) (or fleas, or rat, etc.) which both highlights the overzealousness, as well as the likely collateral damage.

Answer (score 1):

One that I heard once and I liked a lot was "to swat a fly with a Buick".

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange! Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Any expression can be improvised. Killing a fly with any weapon will probably get the point across.

My favorite expression of this type is "to use a hammer to slice bread."

Comment: But using a hammer to slice bread is an example of absurd unsuitability, not of absurd overkill.

Comment: I suppose that's true. How about "electric chainsaw"?

Answer (score -2):

I've often used the phrase

> Using a cannon to kill a housefly

(or some variant) to communicate an extreme solution to a problem.

Answer (score -4):

' killing a butterfly with a gun'

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but good answers have supporting documentation.