# Overkill or wrong tool idiom

Tags: idioms

Is there another idiom for using too strong a tool for the job: not "bring a gun to a knife fight" or "use a sledgehammer to crack a nut"? Or turn it around - one about using a simpler, more direct tool? It may be "kill a fly with..." But nothing I end it with sounds like what I a, looking for. Bazooka, maybe.

Comment: Google autocomplete suggests "cannon" and "sledgehammer"

Comment: Possible duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14685/17611

Answer (score 1):

Googling "using a * to kill flies" (with a wildcard) yields, in the first two pages of results,

> *hammer,
>
>   bazooka,
>
>   shotgun,
>
>   sledgehammer,
>
>   flamethrower,
>
>   bullet,
>
>   cannon,
>
>   battleship,
>
>   machine gun,
>
>   howitzer,
>
>   tank,*

as well as *flyswatter*.  So it's clear that *using X to kill flies* is an established idiom, but there's no single word that is predominantly used for *X*. Pick your favorite weapon or tool and insert it.

Answer (score 1):

I like the phrase, "*Kill two birds with one small thermonuclear device.*"

Comment: Or I just came up with one, *"Kill two birds with a nuclear-powered sledgehammer"*. Or like any kind of oversized or bulky weapon that makes sense, I guess. I think your version is pretty great too though.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't do that. You'd be killing a fly **with a cannonball**."