# Word or phrase for a disproportionately strong measure

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for a word or a phrase that describes an unduly big action to solve a problem that otherwise could be solved with moderate efforts.
For instance, you have a pending application in a government department, and you want it to be processed quickly. You have two influential friends: A and B. A has a good reputation in the department in question, and one call from him would expedite the process. B is a national figure, who has goodwill across departments, and is a much bigger name than A. What would I call my action of choosing to take B’s help, even if I know that A’s help would suffice.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276018/an-idiom-for-striking-unnecessarily-hard-when-the-opponent-is-already-weakened

Comment: @mtugglet Thanks. I found a suitable word through this link.

Comment: Not an exact match, but consider [*over-the-top*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/over+the+top).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some examples come to mind. The one I use most frequently is

> "You don't swat a fly with a sledgehammer."

And I do recall reading one in Robert Heinlein's sci-fi novel *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* in which one of the characters says

> "You don't spank a baby with an ax."

That sounds a bit over the top (I wouldn't spank a baby with *any*thing, much less an ax) and makes me queasy. Which is why I use the fly/sledgehammer trope.