# A proverb that means "using big measures/actions for small things"

Tags: proverb-requests

In Vietnamese we have a proverb that would translate as "you dont kill a chicken with a blade that you would use to hack a buffalo".

It's been in my mind for some work-related stuff and i cant think of an equivalent proverb or phrase in English. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: In English we speak of “using a sledgehammer to crack a nut”.

Comment: Related thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289167/saying-for-using-an-overly-powerful-tool-to-fix-a-minor-problem